# Pipeline B is not being triggered from another pipeline A if pipeline status of A is warning in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any provision to trigger pipeline from another pipeline based on the status of triggering pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Any more information? What did you try? What are you looking for? What issues did you run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any provision to trigger pipeline from another pipeline based on the status of triggering pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Generally, we could set the [pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to trigger another pipeline. But from the official doc, it seems there is **no** such way to judge the status of the dependency pipeline.

Based on my test, the warning Pipeline A indeed could trigger the Pipeline B.

**Workaround:**

You could try to use the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) extension.  This extension contains the `Trigger Build task`

Here are the steps:

In Pipeline A: You could add the trigger build task at the end of the Pipeline A definition.

For example:

```
- task: TriggerBuild@3
  inputs:
    definitionIsInCurrentTeamProject: true
    buildDefinition: 'Pipeline B'
    queueBuildForUserThatTriggeredBuild: true
    ignoreSslCertificateErrors: false
    useSameSourceVersion: false
    useCustomSourceVersion: false
    useSameBranch: true
    waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: false
    storeInEnvironmentVariable: false
    authenticationMethod: 'Personal Access Token'
    password: 'PAT token'
    enableBuildInQueueCondition: false
    dependentOnSuccessfulBuildCondition: true
    dependentBuildsList: 'Pipeline A'
    dependentOnFailedBuildCondition: false
    checkbuildsoncurrentbranch: false
    failTaskIfConditionsAreNotFulfilled: false
condition: always()
```

Note: You need to add the Personal Access Token to this task and set the condition as `always()`.

In Pipeline B:

Remove the Pipeline resource trigger.

In this case, only when the pipeline A is successful , it will trigger the Pipeline B.

If the Pipeline A is warning or failed, it will not trigger the Pipeline B.

By the way, I notice that you have reported a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1091882/pipeline-trigger-should-be-available-with-conditio.html) on UserVoice site.

Before that, you can try this workaround.

Hope this helps.